# Is there a way to create a text that has a background image in CSS

Tags: css

`<h2> MyTitle </h2>`

I need to put a background-image to `MyTitle` text but only to `MyTitle` text.

I dont want any background in the `<h2></h2>` element.

Is there a way to do that in css?

Comment: You mean in the browser's title bar?

Comment: The background-image property does just that, but you can't set styles in the title element.

Comment: Why on earth would you need a background image on the text in the title tag, are you sure your not thinking of a favicon ?

Comment: Do you mean the browser's title bar (like Pekka asked) or a heading on the page itself?

Comment: oh my its just a heading on a page not a title.. my bad!

Comment: @Viruzzo Yes you can. http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-hidden-elements

Comment: @BerkerYüceer I’ve updated my answer now that you mentioned you want to style a heading and not the `<title>`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338846/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-text-that-has-a-background-image-in-css/8338869#8338869

Comment: @MathiasBynens that's an entirely different concept (and semantically horrible), you can't style the title bar

Comment: @Viruzzo That doesn’t change the fact that it is possible to style the `<title>` element. Not sure what your point is.

Comment: @MathiasBynens it is that if the request was to style an element that appeared in the client area, that could have been done with any other tag (as there's no reason to use the title element in the body, and it's ugly to boot); if he wanted to style the title bar, he can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<title>MyTitle</title>
<style>
  head { display: block; }
  title { display: inline; background: lime; }
</style>
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/abitek

This is an example with a simple background color, but of course you could use `background-image` as well.

See [***Displaying hidden elements like `<head>` using CSS***](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-hidden-elements).

---

**Edit now that OP mentioned he meant a heading (e.g. `<h1>`) and not a `<title>`:**

The key is to use `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<title>Test</title>
<style>
  h1 { display: inline; background: lime; }
</style>
<h1>Test</h1>
<p>Some content.
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ekusad

Again, this is an example with a simple background color, but of course you could use `background-image` as well.

Comment: What is this? There's no way to add an image to a `<title>` element!

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks I think I just proved that in fact you can. It’s not possible to do it in the browser’s title bar though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure what you mean with the `title` element as this is by default an invisible element in the `head` section, but I think I somehow grasp what you mean with having the background only behind the text. Try this, the background image is applied only to the text and the rest of the `title` element doesn't get the background image. Note that this doesn't work for the `title` element in the `head` section of your html page. It's just to indicate to you how you could set a background to a text only.

**HTML**

```
<title> <span>My Text</span> </title>
```

**CSS**

```
title > span {
 background-image: url(myimage.png);
}
```

Comment: nice one, i really liked the way of thinking.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a bg image to some title text by wrapping the desired text in a span and setting the css like so:

HTML

```
<h1>My title.<span class="myTitleBG"> My Red Title. </span>More title</h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1 span.myTitleBG
{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #f00; /*for example purposes*/
    background-image: url(image.png);
}
```

IE<7 will not see the `display: inline-block;`. I used this display property so you can add height and width to the span if you need to show more/less of the bg image.

http://jsfiddle.net/b2s9m/

Comment: yea its a good one as i told the same to @Bazzz i liked the idea but while i can do it without extra elements, i would prefer to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to put a background in the titlebar, that cannot be done. Browsers only pick up text from the `<title>` tag and display it according to their standards.

For regular text in the body, you can use CSS to have a background like this,

```
<p class="backgroundText"> My text </p>
```

and define `backgroundText` class in your CSS.